# Keras - no good way to stop and resume training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

After a lot of research, it seems like there is no good way to *properly* stop and resume training using a Tensorflow 2 / Keras model. This is true whether you are using `model.fit()` *or* using a custom training loop.

There seem to be 2 supported ways to save a model while training:

1. Save just the weights of the model, using `model.save_weights()` or `save_weights_only=True` with `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`. This seems to be preferred by most of the examples I've seen, however it has a number of major issues:

   - The optimizer state is not saved, meaning training resumption will not be correct.
   - Learning rate schedule is reset - this can be catastrophic for some models.
   - Tensorboard logs go back to step 0 - making logging essentually useless unless complex workarounds are implemented.
2. Save the entire model, optimizer, etc. using `model.save()` or `save_weights_only=False`. The optimizer state is saved (good) but the following issues remain:

   - Tensorboard logs still go back to step 0
   - Learning rate schedule is still reset (!!!)
   - It is impossible to use custom metrics.
   - This doesn't work at all when using a custom training loop - custom training loops use a non-compiled model, and saving/loading a non-compiled model doesn't seem to be supported.

The best workaround I've found is to use a custom training loop, manually saving the step. This fixes the tensorboard logging, and the learning rate schedule can be fixed by doing something like `keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.iterations, step)`. However, since a full model save is off the table, the optimizer state is not preserved. I can see no way to save the state of the optimizer independently, at least without a lot of work. And messing with the LR schedule as I've done feels messy as well.

Am I missing something? How are people out there saving/resuming using this API?

Comment: You're right, no builtin API support for resumability - which is exactly what motivated me to make [my own](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg). Should be released within a few weeks.

Comment: I believe it is possible to use custom metrics when using model.save, due to the custom_objects parameter of the load_model function. I feel like the learning rate schedule can be fairly easily manually implemented, in the way you've said, or even just by taking the length of the output of model.fit and then doing some maths to adjust the results next time the function is called.

Comment: @Arkleseisure RE: metrics - it looks like using custom_objects should work, but it doesn't, unfortunately. custom_objects doesn't support metrics atm.

Comment: My apologies, I knew it worked for loss functions and made the mistake of assuming it would work for metrics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tf.keras.callbacks.experimental.BackupAndRestore` API for resuming training from interruptions has been added for `tensorflow>=2.3`. It works great in my experience.

Reference:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/experimental/BackupAndRestore

Answer (score 6):

You're right, there isn't builtin support for resumability - which is exactly what motivated me to create [DeepTrain](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/deeptrain). It's like Pytorch Lightning (better and worse in different regards) for TensorFlow/Keras.

**Why another library? Don't we have enough?** You have nothing like this; if there was, I'd not build it. DeepTrain's tailored for the "babysitting approach" to training: train fewer models, but train them thoroughly. Closely monitor each stage to diagnose what's wrong and how to fix.

Inspiration came from my own use; I'd see "validation spikes" throughout a long epoch, and couldn't afford to pause as it'd restart the epoch or otherwise disrupt the train loop. And forget knowing which batch you were fitting, or how many remain.

**How's it compare to Pytorch Lightning?** Superior resumability and introspection, along unique train debug utilities - but Lightning fares better in other regards. I have a comprehensive list comparison in working, will post within a week.

**Pytorch support coming?** Maybe. If I convince the Lightning dev team to make up for its shortcomings relative to DeepTrain, then not - otherwise probably. In the meantime, you can explore the gallery of [Examples](https://deeptrain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest).

---

**Minimal example**:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from deeptrain import TrainGenerator, DataGenerator

ipt = Input((16,))
out = Dense(10, 'softmax')(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')

dg  = DataGenerator(data_path="data/train", labels_path="data/train/labels.npy")
vdg = DataGenerator(data_path="data/val",   labels_path="data/val/labels.npy")
tg  = TrainGenerator(model, dg, vdg, epochs=3, logs_dir="logs/")

tg.train()
```

You can `KeyboardInterrupt` at any time, inspect the model, train state, data generator - and resume.

Answer (score 1):

tf.keras.callbacks.BackupAndRestore can take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the callback function as

```
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.experimental.BackupAndRestore(
backup_dir="backup_directory")
```